# 10 million cycle mechanical switch

Tags: switches

I've been working on my electrical switch with 10 million cycles lifetime, and changed the design from using mechanical contact to hall effect sensors as per the advice of stackexchange. However I can't stop thinking about the problem of making a mechanical switch with that sort of lifetime and find it to be an interesting experiment. Is it a solvable problem?

**Here is a quick drawing to show my basic idea:**

[image]

Plates A, B and C are 1 milimeter thick and made of conducting metal. Plate A is perhaps half a milimeter below B and C and thus never touches them directly. When the button is pushed in current goes from B to A and then to C thus forming a closed circut.

If the current is of low voltage (3 to 5 volts, Arduino digital port voltage) then electrical arcs should not form and thus no damage to the plates, am I correct?

The switch is sealed with airtight rubber to prevent moisture from getting in and thus the plates should not oxidize, correct?

What kind of metal do the plates need to be made of to survive 10 million cycles? Preferably something not to expensive.

Perhaps material would fall off from the casing due to wear and tear and fuse with the plates? If so could this problem be solved by placing the airtight seal right in front of plates B and C so that nothing inside the sealed area touches anything and thus no wear and tear there?

Am I missing something or would this work?

Comment: How can plate A never touch B and C directly but allow current to flow?

Comment: Do you have a link to your previous question? What is the normal failure mode of a switch?

Comment: I see rubber elements moving, I dont see 10 million pushes.

Comment: @Cybergibbons: I would guess that he means that A rubs against B and C, rather than pushing against them.

Comment: The (mechanical) distributor points on a car must last way more than 10 million cycles before being replaced

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at the data sheet for the Smartlock® Slide Retainer & Limit Switch which is specified as having a lifetime of more than 10 million cycles.

Answer (score 2):

The things that will make this switch start to fail may include:

- oxidisation of the metal contacts forming a non-conductive layer.
- dirt particles being deposited on the contacts preventing them touching.
- deformation of the metal contacts meaning that A&B make contact before A&C, thus preventing A&C contacting.
- metal particles flaking off and causing a short circuit.

Firstly, one would not make the entire metal parts from a non-oxidising metal, as that basically means gold. They would be made from copper, then plated with Nickel and Gold. The problem is that the gold layer may eventually wear away, exposing the Nickel underneath. One way to combat this is to use mercury [wetted contacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Mercury-wetted_relay). Liquid mercury doesn't accumulate damage, and provides a fresh contact surface every time.

The rubber seal is a good idea, but rubber can perish, and also generate particles. These particles may prevent the contacts touching reliably. If it perishes, it may allow dirt in from the environment. I would try to get rid of the rubber in this design. Instead, you might consider a metal bellows. These things are like a perfect rubber seal. Flexible enough for your application, but with a *much* longer life.

[image: Metal bellows]

Also, there is nothing in the design to protect it against something pushing too hard on the switch. A hard impact could damage the metal plates. I would start by designing a non-electrical 'button' which can survive 10M fairly hard cycles, then add to it an electrical system which detects the movement of the button without being subject any of the impacts the button might experiencing.

Comment: The mercury wetted contact... That is an interesting idea... Requires more containment and precludes RoHS, but I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Before one can hope to design a reliable switch, one must define what constitutes acceptable performance and what constitutes failure.  For example, many mechanical switches as they age start to have very bad switch-bounce characteristics, such that it may be impossible to distinguish between one slow button push versus two taps.  In some applications, such behavior would render a switch unusable.  In other applications, once a button is pushed, repeated presses would have no effect until well after the user would be expected to release the button, rendering key-bounce a non-issue.

If your goal is to have a switch which may be read electronically with essentially zero quiescent current, I would suggest using a double-throw switch.  There are a variety of ways such a switch may be wired such that the static current consumption will be zero whether contact 0, contact 1, or neither is closed (in the latter case, the circuit will continue reporting the last switch that was closed), but a change in state can be detected instantly.  Double-throw switches key-bounce issues, since once a contact has been observed closed, future changes on that contact won't matter until the other contact is closed.

If one can use a double-throw switch with electronics to "debounce" it, I would expect the biggest reliability challenge to be the mechanics of the moving button--ensuring that it moves smoothly without binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 10 million cycles it will have to be non mechanical, but could seem mechanical...

Perhaps magnetically contained moving piston, which could be tied to:
A led / interrupter / detector 
B magnet / HE sensor

But if you need the other properties of a mechanical switch, you would be better off using better stuff, Gem/Metal joints for moving parts, platinum group metal contacts, good plastic for the housings. I bet you could get on the order of 500,000 pretty reliably, but I certainly can't imagine reliably working at the rate of 1/sec for 116 days